# Copying emails from Outlook to Sharepoint

Tags: outlook

So, I've managed to add Sharepoint lists in Outlook. And I want to copy a bunch of emails to some of those folders. But Outlook says that the folder is protected. Isn't is possible to copy emails directly to these Sharepoint lists via Outlook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not.  The recommended approach is to setup email enabled document libraries for those SharePoint libraries, and just forward your email to the appropriate email address for the library where you want it stored.

There is other software that will do this for you:  http://harmon.ie/ or SharePoint Workspace.

Comment: When forwarding e-mail, SharePoint will store the e-mails as .eml files, which are pretty useless. Using a 3th party tool will allow you to save them as .msg files. Or open the doclib in explorer view (action->open in explorer) and drag the e-mail from outlook to that explorer window.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing actually. I just opened Sharepoint, browsed to the wanted project and just opened the folder in Explorer view. And then drap and drop from Outlook directly to the Explorer folder. Works pretty much the same way actually :)

Comment: @KennyBones Did you accept and comment on the wrong answer? It seems like AlexPoint's answer is really what you ended up doing.

Comment: ".eml files, which are pretty useless".  Ummm, what's useless about them?  They open right up for us.  .eml is the new preferred format...

Answer (score 2):

It not possible out of the box to copy emails to the list and have them stored in the .msg format (so you can them in Outlook) and also have the email attributes promoted to SharePoint Columns.

There are a number of products in the market to assist, including OnePlaceMail where you can use the free express edition or the enterprise edition to [save email to SharePoint libraries and lists](http://www.scinaptic.com/oneplacemail.html).  Both the free express edition and the enterprise edition will meet your requirement.

The following 2 articles may assist with the question of Outlook to SharePoint integration:

- [One Way To Fix SharePoint's Outlook Problem](http://informationweek.com/thebrainyard/news/email/232400439/one-way-to-fix-sharepoints-outlook-problem) (mentions OnePlaceMail and other 3rd party solutions) or
- [Five out-of-the-box ways to get Email into SharePoint](http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/five-out-of-the-box-ways-to-get-email-into-sharepoint/).

Email enabling a list may assist in some circumstance but you miss out on metadata and saving emails in the .msg format.

Please note: I am affiliated with OnePlaceMail.

Comment: Thanks James! I edited your comment into your answer.. hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download Sharepoint Connect from Microsoft App Store. You can upload email and attachments to sharepoint from outlook. You need to have Outlook 365 tho
https://store.office.com/sharepoint-connect-WA104379267.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to work around the limitation of accessing SharePoint libraries from Outlook :

1. From the target SharePoint library, select `Open in Explorer` from the Library ribbon.
2. In Windows Explorer, right mouse click on Favourites or Quick Access in the navigation panel and select "`Add current location to Favourites / or Quick Access`".
3. From any email in Outlook, you can select `Save As` and easily navigate to the library via the favourite link and save the email to SharePoint.

Another easy way to move emails from Outlook to SharePoint libraries :

1. Open the library via Windows Explorer
2. Drag and drop the emails from Outlook directly to the Explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this too a little ago. I ended up saving the mails locally (as *.msg) and then I Copy&Pasted them to the doclib using the explorer view. Far away from a smooth solution and not recommended for large numbers of mails, but maybe it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

We have created an Outlook AddIn that is working cross platform/device, hence also working for OWA. We have decided to make the Add-In free to all small teams up to 5 persons. The free version has no restrictions, no ads and support full functionality which includes:

- Save emails and attachments to SharePoint, Teams and OneDrive
- Capture email properties automatically
- Attach files to new email including converting to PDF on -the-fly
- Works cross platform and device, i.e. Windows, macOS, iOS, Android,
  Web

It can be downloaded from https://axpoint.com or Microsoft [AppSource]

Hope this free version can help you being more productive

Answer (score -2):

Out of box ways to [Copy Emails to SharePoint](http://www.sai-innovations.com/sharepoint-email-management.aspx) without any 3rd party solutions

Comment: Can you please add brief description from the link which you have mentioned.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)