# Synchronize Task List With Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, synchronisation

I am using Outlook 2013 and SharePoint online
 I have set up the SharePoint Outlook folder by going into SharePoint, and connecting a Task List to Outlook.
I can move or Copy certain emails to a SharePoint List folder Manually by click move to option

My Question : Can i set up a rule in outlook to move or Copy certain emails Directly to a SharePoint List folder when they come in ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: move it to folder  local items incorrect

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean it moves it to the wrong folder? Or doesn't move it at all? Or do you get an error?

Comment: there is an error , so move it to folder local items incorrect because thats error

Comment: I try to use this VBA code 
`Sub ConvertMailtoTask(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
With objTask
    .Subject = Item.Subject
    .StartDate = Item.ReceivedTime
    .Body = Item.Body
    .Save
End With
    Set objTask = Nothing
End Sub`

and its work fine , but its move the coming email to default Task list ( my tasks) , but i want to move it to specific task list at my site

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't set up a rule in outlook to move or Copy certain emails Directly to a SharePoint List folder when they come in.

**Walkthrough**

You  can enable email for document libraries and forward your email to this email address of this library .

See also

- [Copying emails from Outlook to Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19943/copying-emails-from-outlook-to-sharepoint)
- [Enable and Configure Email Settings for Document Library](http://www.sai-innovations.com/sharepoint-email-management.aspx)

Comment: i do it with this script     `Sub ConvertMailtoTask(It‌​em As Outlook.MailItem) Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem Set objTask = Application.CreateIt‌​em(olTaskItem) With objTask .Subject = Item.Subject .StartDate = Item.ReceivedTime .Body = Item.Body .Save End With Set objTask = Nothing End Sub`
and make a rule with this script , but it move the coming emails to my task list , so i want to copying it to different task list but i cant !

Comment: yes, I read your comments before I post my answer , but you mention at your question Can i set up a rule in outlook to move or Copy certain emails Directly to a SharePoint List folder when they come in ? not to task list also it's VBA code not as OOTB SharePoint and outlook, so if you applied the above walkthrough you can build rule to forward emails to document library email from outlook I also mentioned how to configure that , Hope it helps you ,

Comment: can you give me a way or changing this vba code to be move the email to task list that i was connecting it to outlook with this path ( sharepoint lists \ taher_test - Account tasks ) not to default task list . with thanks.